# Sharepoint Online REST API - what are moveAway and Navigation changes?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, restore

I'm studying the REST API _api/web/lists(guid'')/getChanges API, but I don't understand some of [the change types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj245903(v%3Doffice.15)) and/or when do they occur.

1. noChange: under what circumstances is this returned by the API?
2. moveAway: moving a folder between libraries in the same site generates a moveInto change at the destination but a deleteObject change instead of moveAway change at the source. When do moveAway changes happen?
3. navigation: the link above says its "a change in the navigation structure of a site collection". Googling "sharepoint navigation structure" returns results for "Structural Navigation", and I'm not sure if they're the same thing.